# I'm confused with push() method in Firebase Realtime Database? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to append data to a list in my Firebase Realtime Database. The documentation says to use the `push()` method but doesn't really elaborate on how to use it and the example of it. So this is my MainActivity. There's an EditText where I put a name then when I click the write button I want to store the edit text to the database and add them. How can I do this? So far this is the code I have. How can I fix this?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        private var TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
    }

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val database = Firebase.database.reference

        val editText = binding.userInput
        val writeBtn = binding.writeUserButton

        val listOfNames = arrayListOf<String>()

        writeBtn.setOnClickListener{
            database.child("name").push()
            database.child("name").setValue(editText.text.toString())

            val childEventListener = object : ChildEventListener {
                override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                    listOfNames.add(snapshot.value.toString())
                }

                override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

                override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

                override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }
        }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference push()

```
private fun writeNewPost(userId: String, username: String, title: String, body: String) {
// Create new post at /user-posts/$userid/$postid and at
// /posts/$postid simultaneously
val key = database.child("posts").push().key
if (key == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Couldn't get push key for posts")
    return
}

val post = Post(userId, username, title, body)
val postValues = post.toMap()

val childUpdates = hashMapOf<String, Any>(
        "/posts/$key" to postValues,
        "/user-posts/$userId/$key" to postValues
)

database.updateChildren(childUpdates)
}
```

I think the code in here means that you should get the push key point by push().key
After that, you can get key path and upload the value. I don't know how to code with kotlin.

In java, it may be work with this code

```
String key = mDatabase.child("name").push().getKey();
database.child("/name/"+key).setValue(editText.text.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
database.child("name").push()
```

It means that you are getting a reference to the "name" property and right after that, you generate a new key. This is what the [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) method does, it generates a new random key, every time you call it. What you are doing using this line:

```
database.child("name").setValue(editText.text.toString())
```

You are getting the same reference that points to the exact same "name" property, and you write the text from EditText to the database. This means that **no** pushed ID is involved.

Now, if want to write multiple names to the database using a generated key that is provided by the "push()" method, you need to add that key to your reference. This can be done by simply saving it into a variable and use it like this:

```
val namesRef = database.child("names")
val key = namesRef.push().key
namesRef.child(key).child("name").setValue(editText.text.toString())
```

And your databqase schema will look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- names
        |
        --- $pushedId
              |
              --- name: "NameFromEditText"
```